# Bold text in email - Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking some way to bold text in **email** and when I open the **msgBox**.
I want bold only headlines, like in picture below:

[image]

this is my script, you choose some cell in row that interests you and run the function. Function show information about data from every cell in row, like inforamtion about "Name" and "email". Then if you push send it will send email with this informations. I want bold headlines for better clarity.

```js
function sendEmail(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  var fr1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var lastColumn = fr1.getLastColumn(); 
  var lastRowValues = fr1.getRange(cell,1,1,lastColumn).getValues();

   var Nr = lastRowValues[0][0];
   var Data = lastRowValues[0][1];
   var Information = lastRowValues[0][2];
   var Name = lastRowValues[0][3];
   var email = lastRowValues[0][4];

  var urlOfSS = ss.getUrl();

  var message = "Message" + 
      "\n " +
      "\nNr: " + Nr +
      "\nData: " +  Data +
      "\nInformation: " +  Information +
      "\nName " +  Name +
      "\nEmail: " +  email +
      "\n " +
      "\n Link to spreadsheet:" +
      "\n " + urlOfSS;  

  var emails = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var numRows = emails.getLastRow();
  var emailTo = email;
  var subject = "Zgłoszenie FAS - " + Nr;
if (email == ""){   
  
  Browser.msgBox('This row is empty - Choose another');
   

  } else {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var l = ss.getSheets()[0]
    var response = ui.alert('Email', "Do you want email \nNr: " + l.getRange(cell, 1).getValue() + "\nData: " + l.getRange(cell, 2).getValue() + "\nInforamtion: " + l.getRange(cell, 3).getValue() 
+ "\nName: " + l.getRange(cell, 4).getValue(), ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  
  
   if (response == ui.Button.YES) {

      GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message);  
      } else {
   Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the dialog\'s close button.');
 }
  }
 }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirement, Only the side headers(underlined in the screenshot) needs decoration.

While going through the Google Apps Scripts - Documentation, I came through this.
Hope this helps you.

Using the HtmlServices & HtmlOutputFromFile() would fulfill your requirement.

Please refer to Custom Dialogs. This would help you
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs